# Ophcrack: how to back up from drive C(sda2) to drive D(sda3) of a windows 7 machine not booting?

Tags: windows-7, linux, terminal

My laptop cant boot. So im about to reformat it, I backed up my documents using live CD Ophcrack, to drive D (sda3). At first I can copy paste my files. But not until im about done, at 75% a weird dialog box appears with a title "error" but a content "success". Really weird, and after that, I can then no longer see the contents of my sda3, and also the partially copied files there.

> I'm new to linux or isolinux, so what would you suggest?
>
> - 1.) maybe I can do some terminal command to enable writing permission in sda3?, how about its content that's not visible anymore? or is my drive D(sda3) gone already? hence, I just want to backup a folder I placed in my desktop (which is surely in C), so I should paste it to drive D(sda3) before I format Drive C.
> - 2.) or the lesser convenient way to address this is that I need to get some hardware to connect my laptop hdd to a desktop and do the backup etc, as what I have researched.
> - 3.) or maybe there's another software that might do the job better?

P.S: the preferred option is #1. But how? what command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this resolved. I guess Ophcrack cannot recognize the command fsck, so I used ubuntu in live usb instead, and fsck /F under the directory where my OS was mounted (drive c in windows)